# Create order programatically without customer

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, create-order

i need to create an order programatically without using customer or ordering as guest, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a file in root dir **CreateOrder.php**

```
 


require_once 'app/Mage.php';
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
//error_reporting(1);


umask(0);
Mage::app('default');

$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
        ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId());

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(231); /* your product ID */
$buyInfo = array('qty' => 1); 
$quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object($buyInfo));
// adding billing address
$billingAddress = array(
    'firstname' => 'Mohan',
    'lastname' => 'Raj',
    'company' => 'Webstocks',
    'email' =>  'test@test.com',
    'street' => array(
        'Sample Street Line_1',
        'Sample Street Line_2'
    ),
    'city' => 'City',
    'region_id' => '',
    'region' => 'State/Province',
    'postcode' => '12345',
    'country_id' => 'NL',
    'telephone' =>  '1234567890',
    'fax' => '123456987',
    'customer_password' => '',
    'confirm_password' =>  '',
    'save_in_address_book' => '0',
    'use_for_shipping' => '1',
);
$quote->getBillingAddress()
        ->addData($billingAddress);

//set shippingaddress, shipping method, payment method
$quote->getShippingAddress()
        ->addData($billingAddress)
        ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate')
        ->setPaymentMethod('cashondelivery')
        ->setCollectShippingRates(true)
        ->collectTotals();

$quote->setCheckoutMethod('guest')
            ->setCustomerId(null)
            ->setCustomerEmail($quote->getBillingAddress()->getEmail())
            ->setCustomerIsGuest(true)
            ->setCustomerGroupId(Mage_Customer_Model_Group::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID);
$quote->getPayment()->importData( array('method' => 'cashondelivery'));
$quote->save();
$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
$service->submitAll();
```

Finding payment method code

```
$allPaymentMethods = Mage::getModel('payment/config')->getAllMethods();

foreach($allPaymentMethods as $paymentMethod) {
    echo $paymentMethod->getCode();
}
```

It working me

Comment: i always got this error 'The requested Payment Method is not available.'

Comment: make sure your payment method enable or not , here i use **cashondelovery** . which payment method you using ?

Comment: i already enabled that method, but still not working

Comment: maybe it will using some diffent code name. i add code to my answer finding payment code try you get all possible payment method, then add than payment